# How do you print in swift only the even numbers from 1-10 in a range of 1...100?

Tags: swift, numbers

Create another Range from 1 to 100. Use it to print out only the even numbers between 1 and 10. You'll need to use an if statement combined with your for loop to pull this off.

Comment: That's a perfect copy and paste of your assignment. Now all you need to do is actually try to do something to complete it. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this office hours.  Try this:

```
for number in 1...100 {

    if number%2 == 0 && number < 11 {
        println(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple. I thought it was asking for a for-condition-increment and so I was trying to set multiple rules. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes you get stuck and go to office hours.  Never ashamed to help someone.